# Is Ruby on Rails suitable for a non-web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qt

I am interested in developing a workstation-based application that communicates with a proprietary data server and that presents information from that server to the user.  I am not intending the user interface to be browser-based, and have been considering Qt as my framework.  Should I consider RoR for this?  Thanks.

Comment: why exactly are you considering a web framework for a non-browser-based app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is specifically a web application framework, however there are [GUI toolkits](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&q=ruby+gui&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=6caa5c396a2de38a) that can be used with Ruby, including Qt (although not the open source version).

Answer (score 3):

Rails is a web framework, so you should not use it.  However, you should absolutely consider using Ruby. I've never used Ruby with Qt, but I've had a lot of success using JRuby with Swing.  I use the [Profligacy](http://ihate.rubyforge.org/profligacy/index.html) gem, which suits my needs quite well.

Comment: Yeah RedCar is a cool JRuby gem too. Its a Textmate clone and I use it for my rails projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ActiveRecord part of Ruby on Rails, which for a long time was the most interesting part of RoR. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Alternatively, use another Ruby ORM, like DataMapper: http://datamapper.org/

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't notice your comment.

Comment: +1 for AR. @vise, you guys weren't too far apart so don't beat yourself up ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Being a web framework you may not use rails, but you may certainly use some parts of rails.

For example just use `require 'active_record'` and you instantly have access to AR and all its magic - validations, belongs_to, has_many and other similar associations.

Comment: +1 for active_record. Using the backend of Rails for database transactions is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. I've been working on a project, Qt on Rails, which combines Qt with a Rails back end. The end result is that you can develop your Qt app's in Ruby, harness the libraries of Rails and there's support for scaffolding of apps as well.

It’s still a 'Work In Progress' but the current latest version at the Qt on Rails github repository (http://github.com/theirishpenguin/qtonrails) will certainly give a flavour of where the project is headed. Contributors and feedback is most welcome and [detailed blog post](http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2010/06/21/qt-on-rails-v0-1-released-but-is-this-ruby-based-qt-and-kde-app-framework-doomed) is available on the project.